# "It ill behooves us alleged early film lovers to forsake their insights today.”

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

This is from one of the LSATs.

*"It ill behooves us alleged early film lovers to forsake their insights today.”*

I don't understand what's the omitted subject being reduced by "alleged ......to". Could anyone help parse it out, please?

Appreciatively,

Leon

Comment: Someone else can handle a formal answer with grammar explanations, but I can tell you that "alleged early film lovers" is describing "us".  Meaning that in this sentence "us" refers to people who allegedly love early films. The sentence could be rephrased as "It ill behooves alleged early film lovers like us to forsake their insights."

Comment: Thank you, Windblade. Your comment surely solved my question.